# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.10 with ATI HD6450G

Tags: installation, boot, 12.10, ati

I'm having problems booting the new ubuntu in my laptop, it stucks on the loading screen. I think may be my Graphic Card (an ATi HD6450G).

I can't find the alternate installation , someone can help me?

I'm trying to boot from an USB flash memory to do a clean install.

Answer (score 2):

did you try to use `nomodeset` at boot? If you boot from LiveCD or USB you can select it under »Advanced Options« or something similar.

It should disable the automatic graphics acceleration, so that you'll get to the ubuntu desktop and can install the OS.

I had to use it with my NVidia Card all the time...